# Dative Bond in Nitrogen Dioxide

Tags: bond, molecular-structure

I learnt that a coordinate covalent bond forms only when

1. Donor atom has a complete octet and also has at lest 1 lone pair.
2. The receiving atom must have an incomplete octet and possess at least 1 empty orbital.

So how does nitrogen in Nitrogen Dioxide forms a dative bond with one oxygen atom while the octet of nitrogen is incomplete?

Also is this the reason why it dimerizes?

i.e.

[image: Dimerization of Nitrogen Dioxide]

I mean by doing so it completes the octet.
And the equilibrium constant for the reaction is about 29 orders of magnitude at 77.15 K.

Comment: There are no dative bond in $\ce{NO2}$ and in $\ce{N2O4}$ In both molecules, the nitrogen atom is charged positively and one of the oxygen atom is charged negatively

Comment: I think the charge is carried  by the molecule as a whole. What you might be referring to is the formal charges. I tried checking other sources also, but they mentioned presence of dative bond as well

Comment: The molecules $\ce{NO2}$ and $\ce{N2O4}$ are not charged as a whole.

Comment: Yes I mean the positive and negative cancel. So the molecules are neutral.

Comment: @Maurice I think the OP is using the term coordinate bond to refer to the N-O single bond... just like nitric acid can be shown with a coordinate bond too.

Comment: @Barry Where did you see those two conditions?

Comment: Yes I mean the single bond between Nitrogen and Oxygen.

Comment: I was taught about those conditions from my teacher.

Comment: @TRC. OK. The concept of a single dative bond between $\ce{N}$ and $\ce{O}$ may be accepted.  It is not the way I teach it, but why not ? In my concept, when an electron pair is given from $\ce{N}$ to $\ce{O}$, it produces a negative charge on the oxygen atom, and a positive charge on the nitrogen atom.

Comment: @Maurice True, even with a dative bond (the way I have been taught) the formal charges will be +1 on N and -1 on O, same as your depiction.

Comment: @Barry Can you ask your teacher for a reference? Or better still, ask them directly about $\ce{NO2}$ and how it fits with the conditions.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry but as the current circumstances stand, I can't contact him.